# HTML 5 Audio API, Conditional Operator(Error)

Tags: javascript

Code: 
https://github.com/MANTENN/Days4God/commit/3b5928eab85cb1ca97fae4d6aa1c9f2c54d7105c
Line 215

> "if(audio.error == null) {"

When the Audio tag gets created, the error doesn't get detected, and the next line of code gets executed.

test input(textarea)

> **01.** Ты есть 
> **02.** Як я жив 
> **03.** Смотрят они не
>   видят 
> **04.** Не суди другого
>   
> **05.** У креста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used on play and error to handle this problem, works like a champ.
readyState nor error.code do not help.